# How can I pass parameters to an Action using Html.Action() in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

I've been using `Html.Action("ActionName", "ControllerName")` to invoke child actions across controllers without needing to have the view in Views\Shared. This has been working great for displaying things like session or cookie information.

Instead of just accessing cookies, I would like to pass additional parameters to `Html.Action("ActionName", "ControllerName")` so the action can execute different code based on the the data passed to the original view.

Should I be using a different method to pass parameters to a child action in a different controller? How would one accomplish this?

Comment: Check this: https://www.codingfusion.com/Post/Passing-Parameters-to-an-Action-with-Html-Action--in-ASP-NET-MVC

Answer (score 117, accepted):

You could specify additional data in the RouteValues property like this.

```
Html.Action("ActionName","Controller", new { id = 1 })
```

Comment: Aw Sweet!!! I saw RouteValues in the intelisense but I didn't use that format. I tried `Html.Action("Action", "Controller", model.Paramter)`. I'm gonna try this right away.

Comment: How do you pass a string, like the text, or the id of an auto populated drop-down list item?

Comment: @antman1p That sounds like a new question, not a comment.  Post a link to the new question here and I will help as much as possible. One thing, it sounds like what you are trying to do happens at the client, as it depends on interaction with the user (browser), while this question in particular refers to how to get a link to an action that includes a parameter that is rendered on a view on the server side.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28701611/how-do-i-pass-the-string-value-parameter-of-the-selected-list-item-from-an-auto

Answer (score 1):

To add a little on this question, I am using ASP.Net MVC 5 and I could succeed to achieve this with this code:

```
@Html.Action("foo",new {parameter1=1})
```

Comment: That is an overload of the same method. In that overload it is assumed you are calling the same controller that was used to render the current view and the action is "foo".  There are couple of other overloads worth mentioning:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.childactionextensions.action%28v=vs.118%29.aspx