# How do I pass the string value parameter of the selected list item from an auto-populated dropdown list to a partial view controller in MVC 4?

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I have created an auto-populated drop downlist on my MVC 4 web application.  When the user selects an item from the dropdown list, I want the partial view to show the item selected rather than all items as it already displays in this partial view.
How do I pass the string value parameter of the selected list item from an auto-populated dropdown list to a partial view controller?
Here is the code for my auto populated dropdown list:

```
 @foreach (var m in ViewDatamodel)
 {
      if (m.State == "In Work")
      {
           <li><a href="@Html.RenderAction("_GetforStatus", "Status" /@* I am assuming that I need to place the TargetName here, but not too sure exactly how *@)">@m.TargetName</a></li>
      }
  }
```

I want to pass the m.TargetName string as a parameter so that i can manuipulate the partialview based on which list item is selected.  The partialview consists of progress bars for jobs being performed where the data is stored on a SQL Server DB.  I use the following Ajax Script to refresh the original partial view every 3 seconds.  I need to be able to do the same with the selectedd partial views.  Again, this is all autopopulated, so I am assuming the best way is to go by the TargetName:

```
 <script>
      function loadpartialView()  {
           $.ajax({
                url:  '@Url.Action("_GetfoeStatus', "Status")',
                type:   'POST',
                data:  '{}',  //I am assuming that I will need to pass the parameter to here
                cache:  'false',
                async:  'true',
                success:  function (result)  {
                     $('#progress').html(result);
                }
            });
       }
       $(function() //..... Refresh Timer
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both the Action and RenderAction methods have overloads that allow you to pass additional parameters that are appended to the query string for the resource.

If you are doing this on the server side, you can:

```
Html.RenderAction("_GetForStatus", "Status", new { TargetName = m.TargetName })
```

If you are doing this on the client side, you would have to write some additional jQuery to make it work (or just plain old Javascript).

```
function loadpartialView()  {
  $.ajax({
    url:  '@Url.Action("_GetfoeStatus', "Status")',
    type:   'POST',
    data:  { TargetName: $("#YourDropDown").val() }
    cache:  'false',
    async:  'true',
    success:  function (result)  {
      $('#progress').html(result);
    }});
}
```

I used "TargetName" because I didn't know what your parameter name is.

Comment: Thank you very much for the clear, concise, and detailed explanation!

Comment: I'm getting an "Cannot implicity convert type 'void' to 'object' error when I use your server side example.

Comment: OK, I used Action instead of renderAction and the message went away.

Comment: Would you mind voting my question up?  Thanks again.  I also have a related question because I'm stuck again.

Comment: I've been messing with this for a while now.  I'm not sure how to get this to work exactly.  I thought about trying to make a default cookie and then change its value when a list item is selected, then pass the cookie value to the action.  I can;t figure thqat part out.  I also cannot figure out how to have two actions named the same, but where one accepts a parameter and one does not.

Comment: I figured out that in your solution above you wrote #YourDropDown").value()  my dropdown id's are autopopulated.  I do not know how to pass the id if I don't have its name.