# Html.ActionLink to happen in different part of code

Tags: html, asp.net

I'm trying to make ActionLink which will happen in another part of code something like:

```
  <div class="col-md-4">
                @Html.ActionLink(some button to click and perform "Action"   div)
            </div>

  <div id="Action>
      <div class="col-md-12">
                @Html.Action(some action to be done)
      </div>
  </div>
```

So and Im wondering if it is possible to send a parameter to "Action" because I want to call a View

Comment: - ActionLink will just generates a link to another page <a href="url" /> (you can specify some parameters)
- Action method is used to call a controller that will render html inside your view : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3150491/how-can-i-pass-parameters-to-an-action-using-html-action-in-asp-net-mvc

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.EmployeeID })
```

The Action is something like below:

```
public ActionResult Edit(int id)
{
//action code

}
```

Answer (score -1):

This should work

```
<div class="col-md-4">
     <a href="@Url.Action("TestAction", "Test", new {parameterName= "parameterValue"})">
</div>
```

Make sure `parameterName`in your anchor tag is same as `parameterName` in the TestAction in TestController

```
public class TestController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult TestAction(int parameterName)
    {
        // Do something...

        return View();
    }
}
```